# returning the content of cell X in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for the content of a cell in a given row, knowing its position in the row. For example I am looking for the content of cell 4 in a row of 10 cells. then the content of cell 8 in the same range. Any idea?

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Is this for a Formula? Or in vba?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX to return a value from a range based purely on its position in the range. For example, for your purposes if the data is in the 10 cells between A13 and J13 this might look like:

```
=INDEX($A$13:$J$13,4)
```

The range can be a horizontal row or vertical column. Or indeed an area, where you would use x,y row and column to reference a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
=OFFSET(A1,,COLUMN(A1)*3)
```

[image]